# jQuery selector with asteriks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some multiple radio buttons on a page with a different id. Depending on the choosen value a upload button or a textbox must show up. But because it's 10 times almost the same code (the only difference is a number) I was looking for a solution where I can reuse the code.

Example of two radio groeps:

```
<input type="radio" name="typePhoto2" id="foto2" value="photo"> 
<input type="radio" name="typePhoto2" id="video2" value="video">

<input type="radio" name="typePhoto3" id="foto3" value="photo"> 
<input type="radio" name="typePhoto3" id="video3" value="video">
```

I known there is a way to use jQuery with a * to select multiple elements, but what I want is to use the value of '*' to provide which number is choosen.

```
$("[id^=typePhoto]").click(function(){
        var value = [number after the id];
})
```

Is there a way to do this? Otherwise I have to copy paste 10 times the same code with only a number as difference.

Comment: You can add a `.class` to your elements and take them with that. like `$(".myclass")` also

Comment: The `*` is a wildcard selector, it won't get you a value in an attribute of the element. To solve your issue you could read the `id` of the current element and use a Regex to extract the number. A better solution would be to not use incremental `id` attributes at all and simply traverse the DOM to find the related element. If you can give a more complete sample of your HTML and JS code I can show you how to do this

Comment: You can select them by `name` attribute: `$("[name^=typePhoto]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always reach the id of the current target through the event object,
and then with a little regex you're done:

```js
  
 $("[id^='foto']").click(function(e){
      var id = e.currentTarget.id
      var value = id.match(/[0-9]$/)[0];
      console.log(value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="typePhoto2" id="foto2" value="photo"> 
<input type="radio" name="typePhoto3" id="foto3" value="photo">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the selector to target all element with name attribute value starts with typePhoto .then get the current id using clicked element context this and remove static part using `.replace()`:

```
$("[name^=typePhoto]").click(function(){
    var value = this.id.replace("foto","").replace("video","");
});
```

**Working Snippet :**

```js
$("[name^=typePhoto]").click(function(){
    var value = this.id.replace("foto","").replace("video","");
    console.log(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="typePhoto2" id="foto2" value="photo"> 
<input type="radio" name="typePhoto2" id="video2" value="video">

<input type="radio" name="typePhoto3" id="foto3" value="photo"> 
<input type="radio" name="typePhoto3" id="video3" value="video">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$('[id*="typePhoto"]')
```

or

```
$('input[type="radio"]');
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do that would be to give them all the same class. For instance class="photo-button". then you could use:

```
$(".photo-button").click(function(){...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$( "input[name*='typePhoto']" ).click( function(){
// your code
});
```